# "Do (the) dirt(y) on/to you"/ "do you (the) dirt(y)"

Tags: idioms

Which of the following means *she harmed your reputation maliciously* and sounds idiomatic?

1. She did dirt on you.
2. She did the dirt on you.
3. She did dirt to you.
4. She did the dirt to you.
5. She did you dirt.
6. She did you the dirt.
7. She did dirty on you.
8. She did the dirty on you.
9. She did dirty to you.
10. She did the dirty to you.
11. She did you dirty.
12. She did you the dirty.

Comment: There's also [dish the dirt](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/11/dirt.html) on someone (spread malicious gossip about them), which OED cites from P. G. Wodehouse’s 1964 novel *Frozen Assets*.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom is

> `X` did the dirty on `Y`

So in your instance "She did the dirty on you" (8) is the correct choice.

The phrase does not just pertain to harming of reputation but any form of betrayal.

Here are some examples:

- [Georgia did the dirty on the whole Caucasus](http://www.georgiatimes.info/en/analysis/55492.html)
- [Who did the dirty on Blair & Brown?](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/top-stories/2006/12/18/who-did-the-dirty-on-blair-brown-115875-18279649/)
- [Larry did the dirty on me - Whincup](http://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/sport/motor/larry-did-the-dirty-on-me-whincup/story-e6frey5r-1225964865340)
- [Nigel Clough claims Kris Commons did the dirty on his old club Derby](http://www.allvoices.com/news/8045397-nigel-clough-claims-kris-commons-did-the-dirty-on-his-old-club-derby)